# How to get italic and non italic text with lxml

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm using this command for each row in a table but I'm only getting the text that is not italic.

```
name = ''.join(row.xpath('td[3]/a/text()'))
```

The `a` element has some text in `<em> </em` tags.

```
<td class="cardname"><a href="http://www.mtgotraders.com/store/PRM_Ball_Lightning_f.html"><em>Ball</em> <em>Lightning</em> *Foil*</a></td>
```

I want to get `Ball Lightning *Foil*`

Comment: At least update your question with some elements in which the italic and non italic text are available .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? Whether you use xpath or css selector, the result is always the same. Give this a shot:

```
html_content='''
<td class="cardname"><a href="http://www.mtgotraders.com/store/PRM_Ball_Lightning_f.html">
<em>Ball</em> <em>Lightning</em> *Foil*</a></td>
'''
from lxml.html import fromstring

root = fromstring(html_content)
item = root.cssselect(".cardname a")[0].text_content().strip()
item_alternative = root.xpath("//*[@class='cardname']/a")[0].text_content().strip()

print(item)
print(item_alternative)
```

Result:

```
Ball Lightning *Foil*
Ball Lightning *Foil*
```